# How to move artboard without guides?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, artboard, guides

Help me please, how I can move an artboard without moving guides?

[image]

Comment: If your guides are attached to the artboard it won't work. You have to make them attached to the working space (background). Looks like you have a couple guides already that do that.

Comment: @AshleePalka thx, but how I can copy my guides from artboard to the working space?

Comment: Just make new ones that are not artboard specific and drag them to lay exactly over top of your current ones. Then move the artboard.

Answer (score -1):

just click on art board name and simple drag the name to move art board

Comment: Won't that also move the guides?